# Why does not work routing in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I use the following routing in Anguar 2:

```
{
    path: 'school', component: ShellComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    children: [
      {path: ':schoolId/headteacher/planning/:tab', component: DashboardComponent}]

}
```

So, I have parent route `school` and sub route `:schoolId/headteacher/planning/:tab`.

When I paste link to browser:

```
http://localhost:4200/school/6125/headteacher/planning/classes
```

It redirects me to login, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have AuthenticationGuard and time you want to enter child route the guard fails  and redirect you to login.

Comment: `AuthenticationGuard` only checks if exists session in store. It is!

Comment: I assume that when I paste url directly in browser it resets current session in session storage and  then does redirect by `AuthenticationGuard`

Comment: Yes it can clean up everything. When you open new tab

Comment: But why does it resets session if I dont close browser, only open new tab? I dont think so

Comment: sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage , the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores

Comment: Cause you are using session storage.

Comment: data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends

Comment: Does it mean that session is ends when I open new tab?

Comment: Hm, why if another tab is opened where is session alive, it looks weird

Comment: . Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.